# What are the applications of C3 and higher smoothness of curves?

Tags: continuity, numerical-methods, curvature, spline

I heard about the importance of C1 and C2 continuity/smoothness of curves but every computer graphics text book I read ends on C2 continuity and does not mention continuity of higher degree than C2.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics) says something about it

Comment: G3 continuity (not C3) is important in machine motion and aesthetics. See my answer to this question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496490/motivation-of-splines/2499704#2499704